# AT91 Bootstrap + Bare Metal Application

Tags: c, bare-metal

I am currently trying to understand how AT91 and a bare metal application can work together. I'll try to describe what I have:

- IAR as development environment
- A simple application which I can download via debugger to SRAM and which toggles some LEDs (working!)
- Using SAM-BA I can write this application to SRAM and it will start correctly (LEDs are toggling)
- My hardware platform is the ATSAMA5D3x-EK

Now I would like this application to first run the AT91 bootstrap to initialize all the low level hardware (like DDR-RAM), then jump to my application and run it. I have not been able to do that yet successfully. I am able to start the pre-built uboot binary though so I assume it's not the copying or jump that are failing but my application is setup incorrectly.

As far as I understand, if I jump to an application (I assume this is some sort of "LDR pc, appstart_address") the operation at address appstart_address gets executed.

Now, in ARM the first 7 bytes or so are reserved for abort/interrupt vectors, whereas the first instruction is usually some sort of "LDR pc, =main". Are these required if my application is copied to RAM and executed from there? I somehow have the feeling that after copying my application to RAM, the address pointers do not match anymore (although they should be relative - is that correct at all?)

So my questions basically boil down to:

- What happens after AT91 has initialized the hardware and jumps to my application
- Do I need to setup my application in some specific way? Do I need to tell the linker or any other component that it will be relocated to some other memory location (at91 bootstrap copies it to 0x2600 0000 whereas 0x2000 0000 is the start address of DDR).
- Does anyone know of a good tutorial which explains exactely this step (the jump from at91 bootstrap to my application)?

One more question which I probably can answer myself:

- Is it safe to assume that I will not need to execute the instructions in board_startup.s at the beginning of my application which enable The floating point unit, setup the sys stack pointer and so on. I would say that the hardware itself has already been setup by AT91 Bootstrap and therefore there is no need for such setup.

After thinking about a few things it comes down to this:

- Does it make sense to tell the linker that it should link main to address 0x0 (because this is where bootstrap will jump to) - how would I do that?

Comment: so you want debugger to pass control back to your app after hardware initialization ? but how ? in order to do that, you'll have to modify debugger itself because after initializing HW, debugger will run continuously, waiting for commands from serial port. moreover, memory map will change after HW initialization, and since you would have to compile your app with linker script using "prior-to-HW-init" memory map, you will have to consider new memory map after debugger passes control back to it

Comment: hardware initialization includes setting interrupt vectors, setting registers properly, defining stack, and for AT91, it is fairly simple to do. your app may do all this by itself, without calling debugger

Comment: To be honest, I do not care about the debugger. I just mentioned it to show that my application is working when it's downloaded via debugger (so basically the code is "usable"). I can also do the setup, that works already. My problem (in understanding?) arises when I make the jump from the Bootstrap to my application.

Comment: actually bootstrap is supposed to know where to fetch the application image. if it doesn't, there should be a way to let it know, either through configs, or hardcode that location at compile time. you should burn your app (which is going to use post-init memory map) into upper (user) flash area at specific address, and tell that address to bootstrap so that it loads your app after HW init

Comment: Sorry but you are wrong: The address is hard-coded into at91-bootstrap (it is 0x40000 @ NAND Flash). Copying to DDRRAM works as expected, it will also jump to that address (i verified this by using uboot instead of my application) but I guess then my application will do something it's not supposed to. My application also doesn't go to flash but to DDR-RAM from where it's executed.

Comment: No, it goes to DDR when you upload it from your host PC. I mean, you should burn your app image into flash (0x40000 @ NAND Flash, as you've specified). does your board have burner ? if not, then you're supposed to make the burner yourself. not that hard though

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: For a good answer which really addresses my questions please see the one from dwelch. When mangusta startet to talk about a burner "which I can build myself" it became obvious that he has never worked with such a complex board since (especially for NAND flash) you need to take care of Bad Block Handling / ECC. the board itself contains an integrated Segger jLink AND SAM-BA, both can be used for flashing data (They use other methods than a "burner"). Also, I have stated (multiple times) that the jump to my application works and it's my application code that's probably failing

Comment: Why that may be explains the answer from dwelch below (probably it's linked to the wrong address, therefore JMP/Branch/LDR addresses point to the wrong locations). The answers from mangusta show that he may have some experience with small microcontroller boards but none with such complex boards (The Cortex-A5 is quite a nice thingy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, in ARM the first 7 bytes or so are reserved for abort/interrupt
>   vectors, whereas the first instruction is usually some sort of "LDR
>   pc, =main". Are these required if my application is copied to RAM and
>   executed from there? I somehow have the feeling that after copying my
>   application to RAM, the address pointers do not match anymore
>   (although they should be relative - is that correct at all?)

The first 8 WORDS are exception entry points yes.  Of which one is undefined so 7 real ones...

The reset vector does not want to go straight to main implying C code, you have not setup the stack or anything that you need to do to call C code.  Also the reset vector is often close enough to use a branch b instead of a ldr pc, but since you only have one word/instruction to get out of the exception table then it either needs to be a branch or a ldr pc,something.

if your binary is position dependent then you build it for that position, you can then place it in non-volatile storage, copy and run if you like there is no problem with that.  if you build it for its non-volatile address but you run it in a different address space and it is not position independent then you are right it simply wont work.

> What happens after AT91 has initialized the hardware and jumps to my
>   application

your application runs

> Do I need to setup my application in some specific way? Do I need to
>   tell the linker or any other component that it will be relocated to
>   some other memory location (at91 bootstrap copies it to 0x2600 0000
>   whereas 0x2000 0000 is the start address of DDR).

either build it position independent or link it for the address where it will run.

> Does anyone know of a good tutorial which explains exactely this step
>   (the jump from at91 bootstrap to my application)?

I assume when you say at91 bootstrap (need to use a more correct term) you mean some part specific (at91 is a long lived family of devices) you really mean either some atmel part specific code or IAR part specific code.  And the answer to your question is in their examples or documentation.  You need to demonstrate what you found, examples, etc before posting a question like that.

> Is it safe to assume that I will not need to execute the instructions
>   in board_startup.s at the beginning of my application which enable The
>   floating point unit, setup the sys stack pointer and so on. I would
>   say that the hardware itself has already been setup by AT91 Bootstrap
>   and therefore there is no need for such setup.

if you are relying on someone elses code to for example setup ddr, then it is probably a safe bet that they setup the stack.  fpu, thats another story.  But if that file name is specific to their project and is something they call/use then well, they called it or used it.  Again this is specific to this magic AT91 Bootstrap thing which you have not demonstrated that you looked at or through or read about.  Please, do some more research on the topic, show what you tried, etc.  For example it should be quite trivial after this bootstrap code to read the registers that enable the fpu and or just use it and see what you see.  that is an easy way to tell if it had been run.  alternatively insert an infinite loop in that code and re-build if the code hangs at the infinite loop.  they they are running it.  (careful not to brick your board with such a move, in theory SAM-BA will let you re-load).

> Does it make sense to tell the linker that it should link main to
>   address 0x0 (because this is where bootstrap will jump to) - how would
>   I do that?

The exception table for this processor is at a well known location (possibly one of two depending on strapping).  the exception handlers need to be in the right place for the processor to boot properly.  Generally it is the linker that does the final arranging of code and it is linker specific as to how you tell the linker where to put things so the answer is in the documentation for the linker and also either somewhere in the project it specifies this information (linker script, makefile, etc) or a default is used either global default or some variable or command line option tells one of the tools where to look for this information.  so how you do it is read the docs and do what the docs say.

Comment: dwelch: Thank you so far, especially the part with linking to the "correct" address has given me a hint of what I need to do. Suddenly that makes sense. I also should have referred to the AT91-Bootstrap better (http://www.at91.com/linux4sam/bin/view/Linux4SAM/AT91Bootstrap). It is meant as a second stage bootloader for a typical Linux/Android setup. The boot process is like this: First stage bootloader (in the chip itself / ROM): Check for the exception vectors at any of the possible boot media (NAND/NOR/SDCARD/...). If it is found, execute the second state bootloader.

Comment: The second stage bootloader is the AT91-Bootstrap part (at least I would want it to be like that). It is responsible for setting up DDRRAM and the likes. The AT91 bootstrap would in turn execute the main bootloader (u-boot in the case of a Linux distribution) which would in turn then (unpack and) execute the Linux kernel. I now do want to ignore uboot and the Kernel and instead of executing uboot I would want my application to run. Maybe another word containing the AT91 bootstrap: It is not only inteded for the AT91 range. It is also explicitly intended for the ATSAMA5D3x (acc. to the website)

Comment: After reading your answer, I think I simply need to link my application to address 0x2f600000 (as this is the final jump address of the AT91 Bootstrap part, I will need to exactly look it up again), so I won't have to care about position independent code (PIC). To my understanding, I cannot even generate PIC using my Toolchain (but I may be wrong on this one or at least not without going through greater hoops). So, thank you for your answer very much, I think I have an idea what I have to look at.

Comment: Alright .. i tried it and ... IT WORKED! I simply had to link my application code to 0x26f00000 and it now starts just as expected. So, thank you for your great answer.

Comment: sometimes what you can do is make your binary linked at the same address as and use the same name as uboot and trick it into using your app as the uboot and then do whatever.  sometimes in some systems uboot brings up ddr and such things so in some systems you want to just let uboot come up then use loady or whatever x/y/zmodem transfer to play with your app, then can do the same trick as above and let uboot think it is loading linux but really it is your app.  glad I got you unstuck...

Comment: @TomL. Could you repeat what you had done to make the bare-metal application boot via at91bootstrap? I am trying to do the same, but couldn't find a way to contact you.

Comment: I didn't write a documentation, but what I did was to make a very simple hello world program with just a blinking LED. By default, the application is linked at some start address and the addresses for jumps are hard-coded (therefore no jump to anything will work). I had to setup at91bootstrap which has its jump address set to 0x26f00000 (by default). Therefore, I told IAR EW to link my program to address 0x26f00000 (which makes sure that the actual addresses are correct ("start at that address")). From then on, it worked.

Comment: Interesting. I am using GCC, so I'll look around to see how to do the same modifications when linking. Thanks.

Comment: Ha, I've just been looking for something different and what did I find: the documentation. It's half-german, half-english but even if you're a non-german speaker you should be fine. If you want it, drop me mail at somnatic@gmail.com. Kind regards.